# jQuery hover and mouseout for drop-down menu

Tags: jquery, html, fadein, mouseout

I'm trying to create a simple sub-navigation drop-down menu. When then user hovers over a trigger the #sub-nav fades in with a drop-down menu then when the user moves the mouse away it fades out. This does happen, but when the mouse moves over the nested li's it fades out then in again and I can't figure out why?

```
<ul id="sub-nav">
    <li class="sub sub-profile"><a href="#">Your Profile</a></li>
    <li class="sub sub-upgrade"><a href="#">Upgrade</a></li>
    <li class="sub sub-signout"><a class="last" href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
</ul>

$('#header-user a').hover(function() {
        $('#sub-nav').fadeIn('400');
    });

    $('#sub-nav').mouseout(function(){
        $('#sub-nav').fadeOut('400');
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated, Jack.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to acheive? http://jsfiddle.net/CW7Tk/1/

Comment: Yes, that has fixed it! I didn't think to use mouseenter/mouseleave :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, hope it will help

```
$('#header-user a').mouseout(function(){
    $('#sub-nav').fadeOut('400');
});
```

Also you can try:

```
$("#header-user a").hover(
   function() {
      $('#sub-nav').fadeIn('400');
   },
   function() {
      $('#sub-nav').fadeOut('400');
   }
);
```

OR

```
$("#header-user a").on('mouseenter',function(){
   $('#sub-nav').fadeIn('400');
});
$("#header-user a").on('mouseleave',function(){
  $('#sub-nav').fadeOut('400');
});
```

Comment: That will make the drop-down fadeout when you move the mouse off the trigger, I also want it to fadeout when you move the mouse away from the drop-down nav as well.